# Androidmpchart piechart not displaying single color but displaying colors when more than one

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using  "MPAndroidChart" and  I have three values to be displayed in a piechart which are "Marked For Review","Answered" and "Not Answered" with their respective colors which are "#ff9600", "#68e09b", "#ececf0".
If I have pass more than one value to chart then the colors get displayed properly but not when I pass a single value.

When I pass single value - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdSDH.jpg (Problem!!).

When I pass two or more values - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VEsf.jpg

Here is my code :

```
  int bookmarked_questions_size = 0;
  int answered_questions_size = 0;
  int skipped_question_count = 30;
  public void addChart() {

    pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.pausePieChart);
    String testTitle = tagTestsModel.getTitle();
    pieChart.setUsePercentValues(false);
    pieChart.setDescription("");
    pieChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    pieChart.setHoleRadius(20);

    pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(20f);
    pieChart.setCenterText("" + tagTestsModel.getQuestionCount());
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    if (bookmarked_questions_size > 0) {
        xVals.add("Marked For Review");
        yVals.add(new Entry(bookmarked_questions_size, 0));
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#ff9600"));

    }

    if (answered_questions_size > 0) {
        xVals.add("Answered");
        yVals.add(new Entry(answered_questions_size, 1));
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#68e09b"));

    }

    if (skipped_question_count > 0) {
        xVals.add("Not Answered");
        yVals.add(new Entry(skipped_question_count, 2));
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#ececf0"));

    }




    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals, "Topics Covered");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3);
    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5);
    dataSet.setColors(colors);

    PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
    data.calcMinMax(0, (int) tagTestsModel.getQuestionCount());
    data.setValueTextSize(11f);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    data.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());

    pieChart.setData(data);
    pieChart.invalidate();


}
```

If a single if condition is executed then problem occurs else it is working as expected.

Xml code:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/pausePieChart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/questionTimeRelativeLayout" />
```

Library version : compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your compile dependency to `compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'` I tried your code with that version of MpAndroidChart and it worked perfectly, when I changed to the version you used, same it produced the error you have.

Comment: Thanks , if you could also help me find why it was not working then it would help me in the future as well.